# Match two arrays using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two arrays.I want to match the values of an arrays using ng_if and else conditions as below:

```
var a = {'nishant','karan','jyotsna'};
var b = {'nishant','prbh','moh'};
    <div ng-repeat="x in a">
      <div ng-if="x!=b">
         {{x}}
      </div>
      <div ng-else>
        <div ng-repeat="x in b">
            {{x}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to use array then `var a = ['nishant','karan','jyotsna']; var b = [....];`,use `indexOf` like `ng-if="b.indexOf(x) == -1"`

Comment: Not solved still same problem

Comment: Can you add the expected output? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My problem is in ng-if and else condition.when i matches the value of an arrays.the condition is not runs correctly

Comment: Just use `angular.equals(x, b);` from your controller and then use `ng-if="!equals(x,b)"` and `ng-if="equals(x,b)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `ngElse` is not a built-in directive, but you could just use another `ngIf`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/HB7zK0Q8nGFRkj44U1AR?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="x in a">
  <div ng-if="b.indexOf(x) !== -1">
     {{x}} is in b
  </div>
  <div ng-if="b.indexOf(x) === -1">
    {{x}} is not in b:
    <div ng-repeat="x in b">
        b: {{x}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
</div>
```